# Monitoring virtual machines with nagios

Tags: nagios

I'd like to monitor my vagrant VMs, I heard about nagios and I'd like to know if it's possible to monitor the virtual machines

My server architecture looks like :

**Server**
Ip : X.X.X.X

```
VM1 with http on port 2300
VM2 with http on port 2400
VM Nagios on port 2500
```

Is it possible to monitor it like this ? It seems that nagios is made to monitor multiple servers but I didn't find the solution to monitor inner virtual machines

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand by your question to "monitor inner virtual machines":

Using nagios (or icinga) you can monitor your VM via [ssh](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/remotely-monitor-servers-with-the-nagios-check-by-ssh-plugin/) or install the appropriate monitoring agent within the VM.

I would go with [check_by_ssh](https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_by_ssh.html) if you use a unix-based system within your VM or [nsclient](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/monitoring-windows.html)-application (monitoring agent) if you use Windows.